# Minecraft villagers won’t breed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made an infantile village breeder while running an Apex Minecraft server as shown on YouTube by Avomance. I made my village in a remote area with no other villages or doors within 100 blocks in any direction, I have fed them stacks and stacks of carrots, I have AFKed over night and I got nothing! Well, I did breed 1 or 2 when the farm was new but nothing since then??? I don’t remember doing anything to change the farm. I may have dropped building blocks into the farm and the villagers may have picked them up? I don’t know if that is a factor. The village is working maybe 50 blocks of a nether portal. At one point I punched a villager by accident, I threw a potion of healing at him. Can I start new by killing the villagers I have or will that affect any future breeding. I noticed the villagers do not trade food any more. Could it be that all of their inventories are full?

Comment: Did you deport the new villagers from the breeder, either somewhere far or at least 4-5 blocks down below the breeding group? If not, the village is 'filled' and villagers won't breed.

Comment: I have my villagers going off on a water stream maybe 20 blocks horizontally away from where the babies drop

Comment: How far do the babies drop from the village doors, vertically?

Comment: Vertically they are probably 2-4 blocks below the point where they drop off. Actually I built the same farm on a different location on the server and it works fine so I can just scrap the first one. Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 3):

Villagers don't care about dropped items other than food, so the blocks won't affect your farm.

Villagers do, on the other hand, need to be happy in order to breed. Hitting them will lower their happiness, so in order to fix that, you will need to trade with them in order to raise it again.

Comment: Thanks for the tips everyone. I’ll try moving the new villagers further away, I’ll trade with them all a couple more times. Appreciate the tips!